# Iteratively accessing and writing to multiple files using ofstream

Tags: c++, file, loops

I have a pair of header files. Within IsingModel.h, publically I declare:

```
ofstream logfile1;
ofstream logfile2;
```

Then to open the relevant files (logfile1 and logfile 2 have different names) I use:

```
do {
        name2.str(""); //reset name stringstream
        n++; //increase n value
        name2 << "output_" << gridSize << "_" << seed << "_" << n << "_eqmCalc.txt"; //stream created

    } while (if_exist(name2.str())); //test if file already exists
    logfile2.open(name2.str());
```

Which works in creating the file. Then, throughout the code I use the ofstreams to act on the files, for example:

```
logfile1 << counter << " " << calcM() << " " << calcE() << endl;
```

This is fine for actions that are independent for each file, however when I call the destructor I want to write the same standard information to each file. To that end, I am experimenting with iteratively writing to the files and it does not seem to work:

```
void IsingSystem::test() {
for (int i = 1; i = 2; i++) {
    if (ofstream("logfile" + to_string(i)).is_open); {
        ofstream("logfile" + to_string(i)) << "success" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This instead creates files called logfile1 and logfile2. As an alternative, I tried to create an array of ofstreams:

```
void createFileHandles() {
    const int count = 2;         
    std::ofstream logfile[count];     
}
```

But, I could not work out how to pass this between functions properly.

What is the proper way of handling ofstreams so that I can have multiple files open, writing different instructions to them simultaneously but also have some actions that happen to both?

Comment: Use the array of ofstream. Your functions can accept ofstream as a parameter and work on it. Pass in the appropriate ofstream using function (logfile [index]). Obviously your array should be declared in the scope that does the calling.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a vector of `ofstream`

```
vector<ofstream> ofstreams(2);
//fill vec
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    if (ofstreams[i].is_open);
    {
        ofstreams[i]<< "success" << endl;
    }
}
```

You can then pass `ofstreams` to functions.